# On an inequality involving the abundancy index of the Eulerian component $p^k$ of an odd perfect number $p^k m^2$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, and the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.

Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must take the form
$$n = p^k m^2$$
where the *Eulerian component* $p^k$ satisfies the constraints $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Since $p$ is (*the special*) prime, we have the formula
$$I(p^k)=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k}=\frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p^k (p - 1)}$$
and corresponding (sharp?) upper bound
$$I(p^k)<\frac{p^{k+1}}{p^k (p - 1)}=\frac{p}{p - 1}.$$
We also have the formula
$$\frac{D(p^k)}{p^k}=2-I(p^k),$$
and corresponding (sharp?) upper bound
$$\frac{D(p^k)}{p^k}=2-I(p^k) \leq 2-\frac{p+1}{p}=\frac{p-1}{p}.$$

We obtain
$$I(p^k)\bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg) < \frac{p}{p-1}\cdot\frac{p-1}{p}=1.$$

Here are my questions:

> **(1)** Can one substantially improve on the bound
> $$I(p^k)\bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg) < 1?$$

> **(2)** If the answer to Question **(1)** is *YES*, my next question is "How?".

> **(3)** If the answer to Question **(1)** is *NO*, can you explain/show why the bound cannot be substantially improved?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I am aware of the fact that
$$f(k):=g(p):=I(p^k)\bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg)=\frac{\sigma(p^k) D(p^k)}{p^{2k}}=\frac{(p^{k+1} - 1)(p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1)}{\Bigg(p^k (p - 1)\Bigg)^2}$$
and that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k} = -\frac{2(p^k - 1)\log(p)}{\Bigg(p^k (p - 1)\Bigg)^2} < 0$$
while
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial p} = \frac{2(p^k - 1)(p^{k+1} - (k+1)p + k)}{p^{2k+1} (p - 1)^3} > 0.$$

This means that
$$g(5) \leq g(p) = f(k) \leq f(1)$$
since the computations above show that $f(k)$ is decreasing while $g(p)$ is increasing.

In particular, the quantity $f(1)$ in the inequality $f(k) \leq f(1)$ simplifies to:
$$f(k) = I(p^k)\bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg) \leq f(1) = I(p)\bigg(2 - I(p)\bigg) = \frac{p+1}{p}\bigg(\frac{2p - (p+1)}{p}\bigg) = \frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2},$$
which somehow improves on the upper bound of $1$.

Comment: (+1) Really well written question.

Comment: Thank you for the compliment, @AaronHendrickson!  =)

Comment: So, are you asking if one can improve $f(k)\le 1-\dfrac{1}{p^2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is basically what I am asking, @mathlove.

Answer (score 0):

**Too long for a comment:**

I asked [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%285%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29%285%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+2%285%5Ek%29+%2B+1%29%29%2F%28%28%285%5Ek%29+%284%29%29%5E2%29+%3C%3D+%28p%5E2+-+1%29%2Fp%5E2) to solve the following inequality:
$$\frac{(5^{k+1} - 1)(5^{k+1} - 2 \times {5^k} + 1)}{({4} \times {5^k})^2}= g(5) \leq f(1) = \frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2},$$
it spit out the following **real solutions**:

$$k < 0 \hspace{0.5in} p \leq \frac{4 \times {5^k}}{5^k - 1}$$
or
$$k > 0 \hspace{0.5in} p \leq -\frac{4 \times {5^k}}{5^k - 1}.$$

However, the inequality plot at the beginning says otherwise so I am a bit confused:

[image]

**Have I stumbled upon a contradiction?**

Comment: We have $$g(5)\le f(1)\iff \frac{(5^{k+1} - 1)(5^{k+1} - 2 \times {5^k} + 1)}{({4} \times {5^k})^2}\le 1-\frac{ 1}{p^2}$$$$\iff \frac{1}{p^2}\le \bigg(\frac{5^k-1}{4\times 5^k}\bigg)^2\iff p\ge \frac{4\times 5^k}{5^k-1}$$

Comment: Ahh, so WolframAlpha's computational routines have gone awry again this time, ehh?