# On an inequality involving the abundancy index of the Eulerian component $p^k$ of an odd perfect number $p^k m^2$ - Part II

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Preamble: This post is an offshoot of this [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4169672).

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, and the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.

Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must take the form
$$n = p^k m^2$$
where the *Eulerian component* $p^k$ satisfies the constraints $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Since $p$ is (*the special*) prime, we have the formula
$$I(p^k)=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k}=\frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p^k (p - 1)}$$
and corresponding (improved) upper bound
$$I(p^k) < \bigg(\frac{p}{p - 1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}}{p^{k+1} + 1}\bigg),$$
per this [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4065190/28816).
We also have the formula
$$\frac{D(p^k)}{p^k}=2-I(p^k),$$
and corresponding (improved) lower bound
$$\frac{D(p^k)}{p^k}=2-I(p^k) > 2-\bigg(\frac{p}{p - 1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}}{p^{k+1} + 1}\bigg)=\frac{p^{k+2} - 2p^{k+1} + 2p - 2}{(p - 1)(p^{k+1} + 1)}.$$

As in the earlier question, I am aware of the fact that
$$f(k):=g(p):=I(p^k)\bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg)=\frac{\sigma(p^k) D(p^k)}{p^{2k}}=\frac{(p^{k+1} - 1)(p^{k+1} - 2p^k + 1)}{\Bigg(p^k (p - 1)\Bigg)^2}$$
and that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial k} = -\frac{2(p^k - 1)\log(p)}{\Bigg(p^k (p - 1)\Bigg)^2} < 0$$
while
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial p} = \frac{2(p^k - 1)(p^{k+1} - (k+1)p + k)}{p^{2k+1} (p - 1)^3} > 0.$$

This means that
$$g(5) \leq g(p) = f(k) \leq f(1)$$
since the computations above show that $f(k)$ is decreasing while $g(p)$ is increasing.

In particular, the quantity $f(1)$ in the inequality $f(k) \leq f(1)$ simplifies to:
$$f(k) = I(p^k)\bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg) \leq f(1) = I(p)\bigg(2 - I(p)\bigg) = \frac{p+1}{p}\bigg(\frac{2p - (p+1)}{p}\bigg) = \frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2}.$$

But from the considerations above, we have
$$\bigg(\frac{p+1}{p}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{p^{k+2} - 2p^{k+1} + 2p - 2}{(p - 1)(p^{k+1} + 1)}\bigg) < I(p^k)\bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg) \leq \frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2}$$
which implies that
$$\frac{p^{k+2} - 2p^{k+1} + 2p - 2}{(p - 1)(p^{k+1} + 1)} < \frac{p - 1}{p}$$
$$p^{k+3} - 2p^{k+2} + 2p^2 - 2p < (p - 1)^2 \bigg(p^{k+1} + 1\bigg) = p^{k+3} - 2p^{k+2} + p^{k+1} + p^2 - 2p + 1,$$
simplifying to
$$p^{k+1} - p^2 + 1 > 0.         \text{ (Inequality A) }$$

**Note that Inequality A is unconditionally true (i.e. for $k \geq 1$).**

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Do you see a way to improve on this proof argument (and therefore, on **Inequality A**), perhaps using ideas from this [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4213383), where I derived ever-increasing lower bounds for $I(m^2)$ and therefore, recursively improved upper bounds for $I(p^k)$, by noting that
> $$I(p^k) = \frac{2}{I(m^2)}?$$

Answer (score 0):

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $\gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2)) = 2(1 - p)m^2 + p\sigma(m^2)$, then we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2)) = 2(1 - p)m^2 + p\sigma(m^2)$$
$$\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}\cdot{I(m^2)} = I(m^2) - \frac{2(p - 1)}{p}.$$

But trivially, we know that
$$I(m^2) > \frac{2(p - 1)}{p}$$
so that we get the recursive estimates
$$I(m^2) - \frac{2(p - 1)}{p} > \frac{1}{p^{k+1}}\bigg(\frac{2(p - 1)}{p}\bigg)$$
$$I(m^2) > \frac{2(p - 1)}{p}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p^{k+1}}\bigg),$$
which implies, again from the equation
$$\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}\cdot{I(m^2)} = I(m^2) - \frac{2(p - 1)}{p}$$
that
$$I(m^2) - \frac{2(p - 1)}{p} > \bigg(\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2(p - 1)}{p}\bigg)\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p^{k+1}}\bigg).$$
This gives
$$I(m^2) > \frac{2(p - 1)}{p}\Bigg(1 + \frac{1}{p^{k+1}} + \bigg(\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}\bigg)^2\Bigg)$$
which implies that
$$I(p^k) = \frac{2}{I(m^2)} < \bigg(\frac{p}{p - 1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{p^{2k+2}}{1 + p^{k+1} + p^{2k+2}}\bigg) = \bigg(\frac{p}{p - 1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{p^{2k+2} (p^{k+1} - 1)}{p^{3k+3} - 1}\bigg).$$

From this (improved) upper bound for $I(p^k)$, we get the following lower bound for $D(p^k)/p^k$:
$$\frac{D(p^k)}{p^k} = 2 - I(p^k) > \frac{p^{2k+3} - 2p^{2k+2} + 2p^{k+2} - 2p^{k+1} + 2p - 2}{(p - 1)(p^{2k+2} + p^{k+1} + 1)}.$$

But based on the initial considerations in the question, we have
$$\frac{p+1}{p}\cdot\Bigg(\frac{p^{2k+3} - 2p^{2k+2} + 2p^{k+2} - 2p^{k+1} + 2p - 2}{(p - 1)(p^{2k+2} + p^{k+1} + 1)}\Bigg) < I(p^k)(2 - I(p^k)) \leq \frac{p^2 - 1}{p^2}$$
which implies that
$$\frac{p^{2k+3} - 2p^{2k+2} + 2p^{k+2} - 2p^{k+1} + 2p - 2}{(p - 1)(p^{2k+2} + p^{k+1} + 1)} < \frac{p - 1}{p}$$
from which we obtain
$$p\bigg(p^{2k+3} - 2p^{2k+2} + 2p^{k+2} - 2p^{k+1} + 2p - 2\bigg) < (p - 1)^2 \bigg(p^{2k+2} + p^{k+1} + 1\bigg)$$
$$p^{2k+4} - 2p^{2k+3} + 2p^{k+3} - 2p^{k+2} + 2p^2 - 2p$$
$$< p^{2k+4} - 2p^{2k+3} + p^{2k+2} + p^{k+3} - 2p^{k+2} + p^{k+1} + p^2 - 2p + 1,$$
which finally gives
$$p^{k+3} + p^2 < p^{2k+2} + p^{k+1} + 1 \text{ (Inequality B) }.$$

**Note that Inequality B is unconditionally true (i.e. for $k \geq 1$).**

*Alas, this is where I get stuck!*